# Visual Studio - Unknown black mark like breakpoint in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I am building an asp.net web form in visual studio.
In aspx page i hit some keys in keyboard by mistake.
Now an unknown mark added next one of lines.
Here is the image :

[image: BreakPoint]

What is this mark and how can i remove it?
When i click on it nothing happens.
This is really annoting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what we call a bookmark.

I often use these. Say you in a middle of a routine. You KNOW you want to go some other place in code - look at some code, maybe grab some code. Now, how to get back?

Bookmarks!!!

from menu you see this

edit->bookmarks:

[image]

so, I often will bookmark. Then go on some code rummage hunt, whatever.

Now, to get back? Well edit->bookmarks->next bookmark.

Or ctrl-k, n

So, you can "toggle" the book mark (make sure cursor is on same line).
(so it toggles - you can toggle again to get rid of one).

Or, you can clear all of them in your project:

edit->bookmarks->clear bookmarks.

In fact, I used bookmarks since the old Vb5 or even earlier days.

Even Access + VBA editor has them, and quite sure every IDE from Microsoft has had this feature - for a very long time.

(I don't point this out to be condescending, here and much apologies if I have come across this way - I "only" wanted to share this with readers and you - a long time feature)

So, some love this feature, some don't care.

But, it is handy, and this is especially the case if I have to go search, look at other code modules etc. It can be rather hard to get back to where you were!!!

And I often used them when in a routine that is WAY TOO long and there are way too many routines say in that one big monster class or whatever. so, late nights, pots of coffee going, mind is tired (we all been there!!).

So I can book mark, and now go say ctrl-f to find..  find what I am looking for, and now jump right back to the book mark.

So, for sure - what the heck is that thing if you not seen them before?

So, no worries! They are a really - but a really long time feature of all Microsoft IDE's - as noted going back to even pre-.net days, and pre-.net editors.

It still a great little feature - and one that I don't use a lot, but without question, when I'm in the middle of some hairy cat ball of code? Then yes, I still use them. And I used them for at least 20 years now, and even before I became a regular user of Visual Studio.